# how to select between multiple, activity animations based on button click in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have a main activity in which I have 2 buttons. When I press button 1, I want the main activity to come from left to right and when I press the other, I want the activity to come from right to left. I have already created the animation button but can't find a way to change animation with button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

// set an exit transition
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

Comment: Thnx frnd i correct it myself just now by putting the two animations along with applications on create and other methods into an if else statement..!